# Entity Framework Self Tracking Entities - error calling StartTracking

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, self-tracking-entities

I am using Self Tracking Entities with the Entity Framework and for some reason I am now getting an error when making a call to StartTracking() before I make changes to an entity.

My code is as follows:

```
BusinessUnit BusinessUnitObject = this.settingFacade.GetBusinessUnitByID(idToGet);
BusinessUnitObject.StartTracking();
```

All this does, is use an ID that we have, use the object context to read from the database, and then start tracking on it straight away.

The error is

```
Value cannot be null. Parameter name: trackingItem
```

Upon looking at the actual generated code of Entity Framework, the code throwing the error is:

```
public static void StartTracking(this IObjectWithChangeTracker trackingItem)
{
    if (trackingItem == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("trackingItem");
    }

    trackingItem.ChangeTracker.ChangeTrackingEnabled = true;
}
```

The parameter "trackingItem" is null, but I am unsure why.

Has anyone come across this before? I have been using STE's the last couple of months and this is the first time this has happened.

**EDIT -------------------**

Sorry folks...after a lot of refactoring of my code I have introduced a bug, and the object itself was null, which I was then calling StartTracking() on!